# io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: Call was interrupted

Tags: android, grpc, rpc

grpc call is cancel after making exception as follows:

```
RxComputationThreadPool-3
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: Call was interrupted
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:366) ~[na:0.0]
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onError(ObservableCreate.java:83) ~[na:0.0]
    at com.mindorks.framework.mvp.data.network.AppApiHelper.lambda$uploadConfiguration$12(AppApiHelper.java:647) ~[na:0.0]
    at com.mindorks.framework.mvp.data.network.AppApiHelper$$Lambda$13.subscribe(Unknown Source) ~[na:0.0]
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40) ~[na:0.0]
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700) ~[na:0.0]
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryPredicate$RepeatObserver.subscribeNext(ObservableRetryPredicate.java:111) ~[na:0.0]
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableRetryPredicate.subscribeActual(ObservableRetryPredicate.java:41) ~[na:0.0]
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700) ~[na:0.0]
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$1.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:39) ~[na:0.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) ~[na:0.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) ~[na:0.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272) ~[na:0.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) ~[na:0.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) ~[na:0.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) ~[na:0.0]
```

the rpc call is :

```
  @Override
public Observable<ConfigurationResponse>    uploadConfiguration(ConfigurationRequest request, String action) {

    return Observable.create(e -> {
        try {

            ConfigurationRequest configurationRequest =
                    ConfigurationRequest.newBuilder(request)
                            .setMeta(getMeta(action))
                            .build();

            CONFIGURATION_LOGGER.info("Configuration Request: " + " Server IP: " + Configuration.SERVER_IP);
            CONFIGURATION_LOGGER.info("Configuration Request: " + " Request: " + configurationRequest);

            checkInternetAvailability();

            ConfigurationResponse configurationResponse = machineOperationsServiceStub.getConfiguration(configurationRequest);

            CONFIGURATION_LOGGER.info("Configuration Response " + "Response: " + configurationResponse);

            e.onNext(configurationResponse);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            CONFIGURATION_LOGGER.info("Getting Configuration " + " Exception: " + ex);
            e.onError(ex);
        }
    });
}
```

it is giving this error in different thread pools & it is crashing the application. its occurance is so frequent.